# Открытие htm страницы в приложении, из папки androi_asset

Tags: url, веб-программирование, android, html, java

Вот в чем вопрос: пытаюcь открыть файл, но выдает сообщение, о том что не найдена страница, хотя она там..
в чем я Допустил ошибку?

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
       webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ma.htm");
    }  }
```

Comment: расширение файла точно правильно указано? точно ли htm?
если да, то я бы попробовал переименовать расширение в html

Comment: точно htm, я пробовал переименовывать и менять расширение на html, но то же самое..

Comment: "там" - это где? должно быть в assets

Answer (score 1):

Код правильный, если система сообщает что файл не найден, значит файла **там** нет!

**Там** означает в каталоге `assets`.

Чудес не бывает.